# Connecting to SQL server on the same machine using the server's IP

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL SERVER 2012. I have set up my web server and SQL SERVER. Remote connections (using the server IP address) from other machines are working perfectly.

When I connect to SQL server on the same server using localhost, internal ip and machine name, these are all working flawlessly.

However, when I try to make a connection to SQL server on the same server, and using the server's IP as the server name, I get the following error:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)"

What can be the reason for this?

Are there any settings that can be changed in order for this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Firewall enabled on the server?

Comment: The IP address is correct. Is their a specific rule I need to create on the firewall? Because I don't want to disable it.

Comment: You would create a rule to allow TCP connections on 1433 for the server's production network. Unless you are running a named instance, in which case you will use the dynamic port.

Comment: Can you disable the firewall temporarily to test if it is that blocking the connection first?

Comment: DavidG, I have tried but no effect, so their has to be something else. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is your SQL Server actually configured to listen on the production IP? Run `netstat -ao | find "1433"` from an elevated command prompt to list what processes are listening.